# Approximating functions using Taylor polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

I'm taking the AP Calculus BC Exam next week and ran into this problem with no idea how to solve it. Unfortunately, the answer key didn't provide any explanations.

**I literally have no idea how to proceed with this problem. A step-by-step explanation would be really, really helpful.**

f(0.6) is approximated by the fifth degree Taylor polynomial (x-1) - [(x-1)^3]/3! - [(x-1)^5]/5! . Given that the seventh derivative of f(x) ≤ 2 for all x in the interval [0.6, 1], what is the maximum error of f(0.6)? [Calculator allowed]

Answer choices:

a) 6.89 * 10^-7

b) 6.89 * 10^-8

c) 6.50 * 10^-7

d) 6.50 * 10^-8

e) 7.12 * 10^-7

Comment: (1) Did you mean the interval $[0.6,1]$ (rather than $[0.61,1]$)? (2) Are you assuming that the Taylor expansion has zero $(x-1)^6$ term? If the answers are yes, yes, then the error term is just $\frac{1}{7!}f^{(7)}(c)(-0.4)^7$ for some $c\in[0.6,1]$ and hence $\frac{2}{7!}0.4^7\approx 6.50\cdot10^{-7}$.

Comment: @Ozymandias.Presumably you are referring to the absolute value of the 6th deriv. But without more info, we can replace $f(x)$ by $f(x)+A(x-1)^6$, with any constant $A$, and there is no bound on the error.

Comment: @almagest Yep, I meant [0.61,1]. I see - so the 2 comes from replacing the seventh deriv of f(c) with 2; why do you remove the negative from (-0.4) though? (although you end up getting the same answer, just -6.5 * 10^-7)